# ¿Como puedo transformar un formato strftime("%H:%M") a un decimal?

Tags: python

Tengo un problema tengo que transfomar la hora a un número decimal, por ejemplo la hora hasta este momento es 11:55 y quiero convertirlo a 11.92

¿Alguna idea?

Mi código es:

```
import time

hora_actual = time.strftime("%H:%M")

print(time.strftime("%H:%M"))

a = int("%H")

b = int("%M")


Minutos = b / 60 

resultado = a + float(Minutos)

print(float("{0:.4}".format(resultado)))
```

Me aparece ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '%H'

Comment: Tu código le da formato a un `time`. Lo que no es evidente en tu pregunta es: qué características debe tener el decimal? No es una transformación trivial y es necesario decidir cómo se van a mapear las cosas. El UNIX timestamp es un ejemplo de ésto.

Comment: @Alfabravo ya lo edite necesito expresar la hora de la siguiente manera: 9.45

Comment: Opino igual que Alfabravo. En tu ejemplo 6.50 que hora supuestamente es la 6:30, 6:50, 18:30,  no queda nada claro.

Comment: @Juan Carlos Guilbovich Ya volví a editar la pregunta

Comment: @Alfabravo ya está la pregunta mas especificada

Answer (score 2, accepted):

si entendí bien tu pregunta, creo que esto te debe funcionar. Si no es eso lo que querías, coméntamelo o edita la pregunta.
Este codigo te da una lista de numeros decimales con la hora actual

```
hora_actual = time.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
hora_en_decimales = [int(n) for n in hora_actual.split(':')]
print(hora_en_decimales)
```

Fíjate que usé:

```
int(n)
```

En lugar de

```
float(n)
```

Porque al fin y al cabo la hora está compuesta por enteros, pero tu puedes usar lo que más te convenga.

Answer (score 1):

Por tu comentario basta cambiar el fornato;

```
    import time

     hora_actual = time.strftime("%H.%M")

      print(hora_actual)
```

El resultado para la hora de esta respuesta es 11.37

EDICION:

Mi respuesta cambia debido a la explicación:

```
import time
st = time.localtime()
hora_actual = st.tm_hour+(st.tm_min/60)
print("%0.2f" % hora_actual)
```

Comment: Ya edite la pregunta